# How is it possible to get a random number with a specific probability?

Tags: java, math

I wanted to make a random number picker in the range 1-50000.

But I want to do it so that the larger the number, the smaller the probability.

Probability like (1/2*number) or something else.

Can anybody help?

Comment: *"Probability like (1/2*number) or something else."* -- coding is an exercise in precision. First decide *exactly* what you want, what probability you want, and please state it clearly. Also, is `number` in the numerator or denomenator?

Comment: or do you mean `(1/2) ** number`, because that would make the probability get continuously smaller as `number` increases

Comment: You could do `x = Math.random()` and square `x`. Then you multiply `x` by 50000, add 1 and finally, cast the result to `int`. I'm not sure if all numbers within [1, 50000] are possible though.

Answer (score 0):

You need a mapping function of some sort. What you get from `Random` is a few 'primitive' constructs that you can trust do exactly what their javadoc spec says they do:

- `.nextInt(X)` which returns, uniform random (i.e. the probability chart is an exact horizontal line), a randomly chosen number between 0 and X-1 inclusive.
- `.nextBoolean()` which gives you 1 bit of randomness.
- `.nextDouble()`, giving you a mostly uniform random number between 0.0 and 1.0
- `nextGaussian()` which gives you a random number whose probability chart is a [uniform normal curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) with standard deviation = 1.0 and midpoint (average) of 0.0.

For the double-returning methods, you run into some trouble if you want exact precision. Computers aren't magical. As a consequence, if you e.g. write this mapping function to turn `nextDouble()` into a standard uniformly distributed 6-sided die roll, you'd think: `int dieRoll = 1 + (int) (rnd.nextDouble() * 6);` would do it. Had `double` been perfect, you'd be right. But they aren't, so, instead, best case scenario, 4 of 6 die faces are going to come up 750599937895083 times, and the other 2 die faces are going to come up 750599937895082 times. It'll be hard to really notice that, but it is provably imperfect. I assume this kind of tiny deviation doesn't matter to you, but, it's good to be aware that anytime you so much as mention `double`, inherent tiny errors creep into everything and you can't really stop that from happening.

What you need is some sort of mapping function that takes any amount of such randomly provided data (from those 3 primitives, and really only from nextInt/nextBoolean if you want to avoid the errors that `double` inherently brings) to produce what you want.

For example, imagine instead the 'primitive' I gave you is a uniform random value between 1 and 6, inclusive, i.e.: A standard 6-sided die roll. And I ask you to come up with a **uniform** algorithm (as in, each value is equally likely) to produce a number between 2 and 12, inclusive.

Perhaps you might think: Easy, just roll 2 dice and add em up. But that would be incorrect: 7 is far more likely than 12.

Instead, you'd roll 1 die and just register if it was even or odd. Then you roll the second die and that's your result, unless the first die was odd in which case you add 6 to it. If you get odd on the first die and 1 on the second die, you start the process over again; eventually you're bound to not roll snake eyes.

That'd be uniform random.

You can apply the same principle to your question. You need a mathematical function that maps the 'horizontal line' of `.nextInt()` to whatever curve you want. For example, sounds like you want to perhaps generate something and then take the square root and round it down, maybe. You're going to have to draw out or write a formula that *precisely* describes the probability density.

Here's an example:

```
while (true) {
  int v = (int) (50000.0 * Math.abs(r.nextGaussian()));
  if (v >= 1 && v <= 50000) return v;
}
```

That returns you a roughly normally distributed value, 1 being the most likely, 50000 being the least likely.

Answer (score 0):

One simple formula that will give you a very close approximation to what you want is

```
Random random = new Random();
int result = (int) Math.pow( 50001, random.nextDouble());
```

That will give a result in the range `1 - 50000`, where the probability of each result is approximately proportional to `1 / result`, which is what you asked for.

The reason why it works is that the probability of `result` being any value `n` within the range is `P( n <= 50001^x < n+1)` where `x` is randomly distributed in `[0,1)`.  That's the probability that `x` falls between `log(n)` and `log(n+1)`, where the logs are base 50001. But that probability is proportional to `log (1 + 1/n)`, which is very close to `1/n`.